# Which Google App Engine installer do I want to use for Windows?

Tags: google-app-engine

I don't need Python or Go or anything like that, my app will use pure html and Javascript only, which SDK download do you recommend?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python and Go SDKs come with config tools (needed for upload to GAE) written in Python, while Java SDK has them in Java. So you need to have one of Python or Java JDK installed on your computer.

Also, one minor difference is how you define config files: Python uses [yaml config](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig), while with Java you can do either [yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) or [XML](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig).